# error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when i select date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

i have this gridview, and i use sqldatasource

this is my select command,

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TAXIConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [TripId] FROM [BookingMaster] 
                    WHERE(([PickupLocation] = @PickupLocation or @PickupLocation is null) 
                    AND ([DestinationLocation] = @DestinationLocation 
                    or @DestinationLocation is null ) 
                    AND ([Status] = @Status or @Status is null) 
                    AND (cast([PickupDateTime] as date) = @PickupDateTime 
                    or @PickupDateTime is null))" 
     CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddPickup" Name="PickupLocation" 
                  PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" 
                  ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddDestination" Name="DestinationLocation" 
                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" 
                 ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddStatus" Name="Status" 
                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" 
                 ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBookingDate" Name="PickupDateTime" 
                 PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but the error came as i select date after 13 or else...

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a localisation problem to me. I'm guessing you're entering dates in dd/mm/yy format but ASP.NET or SQL Server is trying to parse them with invariant culture or en-US, which expects mm/dd/yy format. Or the opposite. When passing dates to SQL Server, it's best to have already parsed them using `DateTime.Parse`, or pass them as strings using `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format which is totally unambiguous.

Comment: Also, is your database column `[PickupDateTime]` actually a date time column?  If not, is there a reason why not?  If it is, you don't need to cast it to date.

Comment: i used " [PickupDateTime] " as a varchar ,bcoz its store date time to database, but i need to compare only date not time thats y i choose cast for comparing date..

Comment: In that case you should use the `date` data type. Storing dates as strings is a bad idea for data quality and performance.